# Help with identifying SMD ccomponents

Tags: identification, surface-mount

Can someone help me identify a couple ofSMD components?

Both are from  analog circuits.

The first package marking is 50W.
I'm assuming that it is a JFET, but I'm not sure.

[image]

The second one is marked A6. I'm assuming that this is BAS16 diode, but the package looks not so usual to me.

[image]

Comment: What is the surrounding context? i.e., what device are these a part of, are they part of power supply/digital signal chain/analog signal chain/RF path/etc?

Comment: Fully analog signal chain.

Comment: The first one is from a function generator.  
And second from the audio equalizer, filter.

Comment: Thanks for updating, also interested in knowing the answer

Comment: Consider the possibility  that **A6** is a capacitor, non-polarized, perhaps 1uf ?

Comment: @glen_geek Less likely, since it has an "orientation line". And it's matches BAS216 from NXperia according to the datasheet provided by Arthur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the same website (https://embedeo.org/smd_codes/), the diode can be either UMA6N, FMA6A, BAS216, BAS316 or MMBD4148 ... but when looking at packages it looks like BAS216 from NXperia is our best match :)

Comment: the package is quite big indeed : https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/package-information/SOD110.pdf

Comment: Thank you, yes it looks exactly like BAS216!

Answer (score 1):

The SOT23 package looks a lot like https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/PMBFJ308_309_310.pdf (see section "Marking Code)

Comment: Thank you, looks correct.
May I ask, where are you found the information, or do you already know this component?

Comment: I used https://embedeo.org/smd_codes/, and then when looking at picture : https://www.ebay.com/itm/152974650375, but the number on the vertical is not the same ... but I guess this is just some version number as I saw different pictures with different numbers

Comment: Got it, thanks for the additional information. 
Yes, I believe that vertical marking usually indicates the manufacturing date or something like that. And according to datasheet letter W- is for manufacturing country (China in this specific case)

Comment: yes it is made in China